# how to traverse the element in <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
<tr id="head-58">
    <td style="width:150px;">
        <input type="button" name="delete" class="delete_person" value="58" />name<button type="button" style="margin: 1px 35px 5px;" name="delete" value="58" class="delete_icon button_style">Delete</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="first_aid" id="id_first_aid" />FirstAid
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sick_bay" id="id_sick_bay" /Sick bay
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ambulance" id="id_ambulance" />Ambulance
    </td>

</tr>
```

Here onclicking the delete_person class,i want to show the hidden button with class delete_icon.Since class delete_icon can have more than one,i need to show the hidden button form clicked element.I tried with `$this.closest('tr').find(".delete_icon").toggle();`  which is not working.

Comment: Why is there a `button` outside of the `tr`? `button` and `tr` aren't valid siblings...

Comment: I moved the button inside the <tr>

Comment: You need to move the button inside a table cell, otherwise it's invalid HTML and the button may end up outside the table entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$this.parents('tr').find(".delete_icon").toggle();
```

Comment: Why is `.parents('tr')` better than `.closest('tr')`?

Comment: It depends on the context of "this" which is not exposed in your question.

Comment: Hai,I tried this is not working i thought the button is outside the <tr>,now i moved the button inside the <tr>.How to solve

Comment: What is triggering this event handler?

Comment: This button will delete the current row of data.on load it is in hidden.It is created dynamically with same class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `$this` variable unless you create it yourself. `this` refers to the target of the event, so use it in the jQuery function to create a jQuery object containing it:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(".delete_icon").toggle();
```

However, you also need to move the button inside the table row for that to work. Now it looks like it's inside the table but outside any table cell, which is invalid HTML. (Some browsers may put it inside some table cell, other may move it outside the table entirely. The result is unpredictable, so unless you move the button inside a cell, it's not possible to write code that accesses it.)

Comment: Hai,I tried this is not working i thought the button is outside the <tr>,now i moved the button inside the <tr>.How to solve

Comment: @MonkL: You need to put the button inside a `<td>`, content in a table can only be inside cells, not anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Your delete button is not a child of tr. Move it into tr, or use:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('.delete_icon')
```

Comment: This won't solve the issue as the HTML is invalid and actually it should be child of `td` element.

Comment: yes, moving it into td will be good idea. I wanted to show, that .find() function searchs only children elements and .delete_icon is not a child element, so .next() should be used

Comment: I see, this answer has my upvote as it was the first answer that mentioned the invalid markup.

Comment: Hai,I tried this is not working i thought the button is outside the <tr>,now i moved the button inside the <tr>.How to solve

Comment: If you moved your button inside tr, $(this).closest('tr').find('.delete_icon') should work. As said earlier valid HTML would be <tr>...<td><button></td></tr>, so dont forget to put it to <td>

Answer (score 0):

Since the button is after the `<tr>...</tr>`

Use:

```
$(this).parent().next().toggle()
```

Comment: This is toggling the 3rd td

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the DOM actually ends up with a button in the row collection.

Comment: I moved the button inside the tr

Comment: @MonkL a `button` can't be part of the cells collection either. It needs to be in a `td` or `th`, i.e.: elements which can contain content.